# Run Java application on Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5

Tags: java, windows-mobile, intermec

I want to run a **Java Application** on an Intermec scanner with **Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Operating System**. I used [this](http://www.intermec.com/public-files/guides/en/developing_java_applications_forIntermec.pdf) tutorial.

**The problem is I don't know how to run my application on the Intermec scanner.**

I downloaded and installed **PhoneME Advanced** and **PhoneME Feature** from [here](http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/?q=node/10).

I searched for **JavaFX** like in [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-java-windows-mobile/) tutorial, but when I follow the link to JavaFX on the Oracle site, it says it's included in the current **JDK**, which I can't install (`"The file *** cannot be opened. Either is not signed with a trusted certificate, or one of its components cannot be found"`). I tried installing the **JRE** but I get the same message.

Help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Intermec Java installation doc is very outdated and related to IBM WEME, which is no longer be sold for a long time.

The IBM J9 licensing is strange and can only be achieved with a larger number of installations. But you may get a [validation copy](http://www.microdoc.com/ibm-websphere-everyplace-custom-environment-wece_) from microdoc.com

You may go with another JAVA VM like PhoneME or [CrEme](http://www.cremejvm.com/#!/page_products). JavaFX seems to be discontinued, whereas IBM J9 or CrEme are more or less current and supported products.

Which JVM you choose depends also on your intention. The Intermec Java Datacollection jar will only run with J9. But you can write your own JNI for the native Scanner API.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've installed CrEme jvm and created a shortcut file to run the jar. Now the problem is the console disappears too quick, how can I set an error log file? The shortcut content:
255#"\windows\CrEme\bin\CrEme.exe" -of "\My Documents\TestareIulia.jar" testareiulia.Main

Comment: use -Of [<directory>]
Sets the console output to be redirected to a jscpout.txt file located in the specified directory. If no directory is specified the jscpout.txt file is created in the root directory of the device. Found on http://scn.sap.com/people/veeraraagavan.rajachandrasekhar/blog/2009/03/31/creme-secrets

Comment: Now I'm facing another problem. I'm trying to display an awt frame. When I run the .lnk, the console appears and nothing happens. No error message, but no frame either. When I try to run a simple Hello World cdc application, everything works fine, I see the output in the console. Can you help me, please? I have no idea what to do...

Comment: Which JVM are you testing? Does this support (come with) AWT support?

Comment: I can't believe how simple it was! I wasn't setting the Frame's width and height. I'm using CrE-ME and it works fine now. Thank you a lot for helping me!